# Циклы на assembler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, циклы, ассемблер, ряды

Я пытался написать код, задача которого звучит так: найти сумму чисел натурального ряда от 1 до N, которые без остатка делятся на 3. Я знаю, что задача предельно простая. На C++ она выполняется без проблем, но вот assembler вызывает проблемы. Привожу в пример код, который я сделал (работает неправильно):

```
__asm
{
    mov ecx, n
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    mov esi, 0
    asm_for:
    add ebx, 1
        add eax, 1
        mov edx, 0
        div b
        cmp edx, 0
        JE then
        JNE then2
        then: add a, ebx
        then2: add esi, 1
        Loop asm_for
        mov edi, a
        mov sum, edi
}

cout << sum << endl;
```

Другими словами, как я вижу этот код (начиная со строки "cmp edx, 0"): если условие "cmp edx, 0" ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ, то тогда выполняется действие then, а за ним команда Loop. Если условие "cmp edx, 0" НЕ ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ, то тогда выолняется действие then2, а за ним команда Loop.

P.S.

esi я добавил только для того, чтобы было что выполнять в then2. Никакой роли это здесь не играет.

Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка. И да, советы по ссылке ниже мне не помогли.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42188685/implementing-a-flow-1-if-else-if-2-in-assembly

Comment: Что значит "работает неправильно"?

Comment: Напишите свои задачу на С++, странслируйте с получением ассемблерного листинга и будет всем СЧАСТЬЕ.

Answer (score 1):

Команда [DIV](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html) делит число, записанное в регистрах `EDX:EAX`, и заполняет регистр `EAX` результатом, а `EDX` остатком от деления. Вы правильно обнуляете перед делением `EDX`, но не учитываете, что регистр `EAX` уже занят результатом деления и там нет предыдущего делимого. Делимое у вас хранится в регистре `EBX`. Так что замените строчку

```
add eax, 1
```

на

```
mov eax, ebx
```

Также хочется отметить, что ваш алгоритм можно оптимизировать. Необязательно проверять подряд натуральные числа на делимость на 3. На 3 делится без остатка каждое 3-е натуральное число: 3, 6, 9 и т.д. Поэтому можно сразу начинать с числа 3 и прибавлять по 3, ничего не проверяя. Можно заметить ещё, что эта последовательность является арифметической прогрессией и можно применить формулу суммы арифметической прогрессии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int result = (int) ((n / 3) / 2. * (2 * 3 + (n / 3 - 1) * 3));
```

Comment: 2 * 3 + (n / 3 - 1) * 3 можно оптимизировать как (n/3+1)*3 :) - см. мой ответ...

Comment: Я просто в формулу подставил, чтоб наглядно было.

Answer (score 1):

Если задача строго звучит именно как *найти сумму чисел натурального ряда от 1 до N, которые без остатка делятся на 3*, то я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int N;

    cin >> N;

    __asm {
        mov     eax, N
        mov     ecx, 3
        idiv    ecx
        mov     ecx, eax
        imul    eax, 3
        inc     ecx
        imul    eax, ecx
        shr     eax, 1
        mov     N, eax
    };

    cout << N << endl;

}
```